# How can I stop speed throttling and ignore battery 'empty' 0% status? hardware mod, new battery not worth it

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I have an old laptop, the battery's bms (circuitry to report status) broke, I replaced it, but wasnt able to get one that reports the % to the smbus on the laptop. I still get 3+ hours out of the battery, and only need it as a backup when moving around, so % is not important.

The issue, is that ubuntu sees it as empty and panics and down throttles everything to the slowest. It's all set to run in performance mode, but it still becomes almost unusably laggy.

I wont buy a new battery, it's just not worth it and it works fine the way it is.

The question I want answered, is; how can I either A) Ignore the battery status? or B) spoof a charged battery?  and get it to run at normal speed while on battery

I dont care if I have to add a kernel module or remove one, I will never be getting a new battery for it.